# bash:express:command not found issue not resolving, i did everything from my end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am on window using git bash as the tool:

1)i install express and express-generator globally

2)also set the path of npm global module in path variable.

still it say express command not found.

Comment: Please shoe the command used for install things globally

Comment: npm install express  express-generator -g